# Always display rows that give 0 as a result of count (1)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently had to run into sql queries, although it is not my specialty. The following query is the one I use: my problem is that if the line has count (1) = 0 it is not displayed. The first query is the evolution of the second, which obviously displays the line if the value is 0. The evolution was necessary due to the large amount of agency codes, to make everything quicker and not perform n queries for n codes agency.

```
SELECT
    rollout.id AS 'RowNumber',
    rollout.AgencyCode,
    COUNT(1) AS 'NumberOfTitleAgnecy',
    SUM(COUNT(1)) OVER() AS 'SumOfTitle'
FROM STAGINGTITLE AS ST
    INNER JOIN (
        VALUES
            (1,'000001'),
            (2,'000002'),
            (3,'000003')
    ) AS rollout (id, CodAgency) 
    ON ST.AgencyCode = rollout.CodAgency
WHERE ST.ExternalId IS NULL
    AND ST.TitleState = 'BackWard'
GROUP BY rollout.id, rollout.CodAgency
ORDER BY rollout.id

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM STAGINGTITLE AS ST
WHERE ST.AgencyCode = '000001'
    AND ST.ExternalId IS NULL
    AND ST.TitleState = 'BackWard'
```

Do you have a suggestion on how to modify the first query to have the display of lines count (1) = 0?

Edit: output expected

```
RowNumber | AgencyCode | NumberOfTitleAgnecy | SumOfTitle |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1        | 000001     |  100                | 300        |
 2        | 000002     |  0                  | 300        |
 3        | 000003     |  150                | 300        |
 4        | 000004     |  50                 | 300        |
```

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are really using.  You also say "the following query" and then have two queries.

Comment: If you had read the question carefully, you would have noticed that it refers to the first query, and the second query is only for a better explanation

Comment: Does it work if you change INNER to RIGHT join? Remember that counting is done after WHERE.

Comment: Can you describe what specific result/behavior uou want from this? And ditch that join and use a case clause or a cast as integer in the select statement, instead. That inner join is likely eliminating the rows you expect.

Comment: @dodexahedron Sure: read the edit

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT rollout.id AS RowNumber,
       rollout.CodAgency,
       COUNT(st.AgencyCode) AS NumberOfTitleAgnecy,
       SUM(COUNT(st.AgencyCode)) OVER () AS SumOfTitle
FROM (VALUES (1, '000001'), (2, '000002'), (3, '000003')
     ) rollout(id, CodAgency) LEFT JOIN
     STAGINGTITLE ST
     ON ST.AgencyCode = rollout.CodAgency AND
        ST.ExternalId IS NULL AND ST.TitleState = 'BackWard'
GROUP BY rollout.id, rollout.CodAgency
ORDER BY rollout.id;
```

Notes:

- The `WHERE` clause is moved into the `ON` clause, so the `LEFT JOIN` is not turned into an `INNER JOIN`.
- The `COUNT()` is now counting the number of matches, so it can return `0`.
- The alias for `ST` is fixed.
- The reference to `CodAgency` is fixed.
- The single quotes are removed from the column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Thanks for your help